# converting string to float (and removing decimal point) in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that imports a csv file which holds records for population per year (as strings). It imports a file which has the year in the 3rd column and the population count in the 4th.

It should remove the decimal point '.' and display the resulting population.

```
16122.83
16223.248
```

should become

```
1612283
16223248
```

When I try to do this I get: in print_population_list
    year, population = row[2], float(row[3]) ValueError: could not convert string to float: POP. 
This is my code:

```
import csv
file = csv.reader(open(filename))

year, population = 0, 0

for row in file:
    year, population = row[2], float(row[3])
    print year,":", population,
```

To do this I figured it should first be converted to a float and be multiplied by the highest number of decimal places, after which all zero's at the end should be removed (since the data doesn't all have the same number of decimal places). But I'm stuck at the float conversion.

Comment: Roger that, I removed my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most direct route:

```
>>> s = '16122.83'
>>> int(s.replace('.', ''))
1612283
```

While performance is probably not a big concern in your use case,
a replace strategy is about 30% faster than the split-join strategy,
based on [a simple benchmark](https://gist.github.com/jonathaneunice/d46640740f78ed922a35).

```
Benchmark Report
================

Options
-------

   name | rank | runs |     mean |        sd | timesBaseline
--------|------|------|----------|-----------|--------------
replace |    1 | 1000 | 0.009488 | 0.0006711 |           1.0
   join |    2 | 1000 |  0.01258 | 0.0007729 | 1.32589602108

Each of the above 2000 runs were run in random, non-consecutive order by
`benchmark` v0.1.5 (http://jspi.es/benchmark)
```

For this problem, `int` is what you seem to need. But for related problems, using `float` instead of `int` would keep you in the floating point realm. The `round(value, places)` function also might be handy.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
def decToNum(s):
    return int(''.join(s.split('.')))

>>> s = '16122.83'
>>> decToNum(s)
1612283
```

Comment: this gives me: in decToNum
    return int(''.join(s.split('.')))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'POP'